# Create KML file programmatically in Android app & sync created maps using KML file

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

As of now I'm checking feasibility of requirements & my requirements are as follow :

1. Generate KML file with Lat - Long , Photo & remarks with respective to location.
2. Plot these locations on google maps which can be accessible on both Android app as well as via Web. (Is there any sync mechanism?)

In order to implement this functionality probably I would send prepared kml file to web where I will be handling parsing of it & displaying on google map but I'm open to suggestions to solve this riddle. Let me know how whichever is better way to implment it.

As of now this is research phase so , i don't have any code / sample that I can share with you guys & also I haven't found any references.